# SubsetOf method as actual paramter in NUnit

Tags: c#, nunit

I'm writing unit tests with NUnit. The method I'm testing returns the collection of elements. I wanted to check if it contains the subset of another collection. So, I created a test which looks:

```cs
// Ignore other lines for simplicity
Assert.That(new[] { 1, 3, 4, 6 }, Is.SubsetOf(actual));
```

However, when my test fails, I've got the following error:

```
Expected: subset of < 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 >
But was:  < 1, 3, 4, 6 >
```

which is not quite correct. It should be something like this:

```
Expected: < 1, 3, 4, 6 >
But was: < 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 >
```

Or something similar.

The main idea is that I need to change `expected` and `actual` parameters but can't.
E.g. I can't write something like this:

```cs
Assert.That(Is.SubsetOf(actual), new []{1, 3, 4, 6});
```

Because there is no such method.

I also know that I can run a loop or some other manual solution, but I wonder if there is an NUnit-ready solution.

Comment: `Assert.That(actual, Is.SupersetOf(new[] { 1, 3, 4, 6 }));`, see https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/constraints/CollectionSupersetConstraint.html

Comment: Thank you. It is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a superset constraint, not a subset constraint:

```
Assert.That(actual, Is.SupersetOf(new[] { 1, 3, 4, 6 }));
```

See https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/constraints/CollectionSupersetConstraint.html